# Excel custom data validation - combining a range of numbers with text: "n/a" and "n/c"

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have a column of cells filled manually (no function/formula) with population figures, that I want to be restricted between 0 and 2'000; Yet I would like to also be able to write "n/a" or "n/c" in these same cells instead when needed; How could I do that?

Comment: Sorry, does not work, neither @CallumDA's, nor Axel Richter's (also I see no difference between them): I copy-pasted the formula as you wrote it into the A1 cell in a new worksheet, and got the formula error message. Manual writing brought same result...

Comment: Well, there aren't many instructions in the answer I gave but if you follow them you'll realize that the formula **shouldn't go on the worksheet**. It's a custom formula for *data validation*. Search Google for "Excel data validation" if you don't understand.

Comment: Apologies, my comment was unclear and your first explanation was absolutely clear; I did use data validation->allow->custom and the formula you provided as such and applied it to cell A1 of a new worksheet. May I ask to try again on your side? Is there just something too obvious for me to see what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

Apply data validation *(Data > Data Validation)* and then use the following custom formula *(Allow > Custom)*:

```
=OR(AND(A1>=0,A1<=2000),A1="n/a",A1="n/c")
```

Change `A1` to the cell you are applying the data validation to.

Comment: Please check your formula. It should be `=OR(AND(A1>=0,A1<=2000),A1="n/a",A1="n/c")`, shouldn't it`?

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, I'm losing the plot!

Comment: You should not use `"n/a"` as an option. You should either use a null value, or if you must use Excel's `=NA()`. This can then be used with the Excel function `=ISNA(A1)` more robustly than using a text lookup.

Comment: @SandPiper, from an Excel point of view I agree but from a readability point of view I disagree. Someone non-technical would likely rather receive a report with "n/a" the common abbreviation of "not applicable" rather than #N/A - which will probably make them worry that the numbers have broken

Comment: I see your point, but I suppose it depends entirely on who the end user will be for the data. It is a good consideration though.